# ssh to execute all commands in guest machine

Tags: unix, ssh, sh, raspberry-pi

i was created a bash script my_vp.sh that use 2 command:

```
    setterm -cursor off
    setterm -powersave off
    [...]
    #execute video commands
    [...]
```

and is in a computerA

but when i execute it by ssh by another computerB_terminal:

```
ssh pi@192.168.1.1
```

execute video commands work correctly in the computerA (the same where is the script)
but the command setterm works in the computerB (the terminal where i execute the ssh command).

somebody can help me with solucione it? 
thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood the question:

- to execute a local script, but on another machine:

  `scp /path/to/local/script.bash pi@192.168.1.1:/tmp/copy_of_script.bash`

  and then, if it's copied correctly, execute it:

  `ssh pi@192.168.1.1 "chmod +x /tmp/copy_of_script.bash"`

  `ssh pi@192.168.1.1 "bash /tmp/copy_of_script.bash"`
- to have the remote video (Xwindows, etc) commands appear on the originating machine:

  replace : `ssh`  with : `ssh -x`   (to allow X-Forwarding, which will allocate a DISPLAY automatically on the remote machine that will be tunneled back to the originating machine)

for the X-forwarding to work, there are some requirements (usually ok by default, but ymmv) : read more about those requirements [in this Unix.se answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12772/27616)

Comment: @UserRaspberry: me neither ^^ Please rephrase your question, as it is not really clear what you are attempting to do, on which machine, why it fails, etc... It's possible my guess is way out of the real question (If it is a matter of langage, try to ask a friend to help you reformulate it).

Comment: i'm Sorry but i don't understand... i have a computerA with: playVideoScript.sh, video.avi, monitor. y have a computerB (my macbook). I Write    in macbook terminal "ssh pi@192.168.40.1" and i have to put the password of pi. When I execute (from computerB macbook by ssh) playVideoScript.sh i can see the video in the correct monitor of computerA (like i wont) but in this script doesn't no execute 3 command:1) setterm -cursor off 2) setterm -powersave off 3)clear. thank you and sorry... i hope of explain good my problem... :(